# Why does pandas pipe change the dataframe in place when columns are added, but not when columns or rows are removed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whenever a function used in `pipe` adds columns, the DataFrame is affected in place. However, when the function removes rows or columns, the original DataFrame is not affected.

Is this how it is supposed to work? How can I ensure the DataFrame is always affected in place without having to re-assign the variable?

```py
# Dummy data
tdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], b=[33, 22, 66, 33, 77]))

# Functions to pipe
def addcol(dataf):
    dataf["c"] = 1000
    return dataf

def remcol(dataf):
    dataf = dataf.drop(columns='c')
    return dataf

def addrow(dataf):
    dataf = pd.concat([dataf, dataf])
    return dataf

def remrow(dataf):
    dataf = dataf.loc[dataf.a < 4]
    return dataf

# Utility function to print result
def printer(pdf, funcname):
    shape1 = pdf.pipe(eval(funcname)).shape
    shape2 = pdf.shape
    if (shape1 == shape2):
        print(f"{funcname}: DataFrame updated in place: shape1 = {shape1}, shape2 = {shape2}")
    else:
        print(f"{funcname}: DataFrame NOT updated in place: shape1 = {shape1}, shape2 = {shape2}")

for fn in ["addcol", "remcol", "addrow", "remrow"]:
    printer(tdf, fn)
```

```
addcol: DataFrame updated in place: shape1 = (5, 3), shape2 = (5, 3)
remcol: DataFrame NOT updated in place: shape1 = (5, 2), shape2 = (5, 3)
addrow: DataFrame NOT updated in place: shape1 = (10, 3), shape2 = (5, 3)
remrow: DataFrame NOT updated in place: shape1 = (3, 3), shape2 = (5, 3)
```

Pandas version is `2.0.0`

Comment: Because `dataf["c"] = 1000` is the only operation that actually does an inplace update? `addcol` takes the dataframe _by reference_, updates it, and returns it. All other functions don't operate by reference due to the `dataf = ...`. That's a Python feature and has nothing to do with Pandas `.pipe`.

Comment: Ok, so how can I re-write the other functions such that they also operate by reference? Writing `return (pd.concat([dataf, dataf]))` in `addrow` for example does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to *re-write the other functions such that they also operate by reference*:

```py
def remcol(dataf):
    dataf.drop(columns="c", inplace=True)
    return dataf


def addrow(dataf):
    dataf.loc[dataf.shape[0]] = dataf.loc[dataf.shape[0] - 1]
    return dataf


def remrow(dataf):
    dataf.drop(index=dataf[~dataf.index.isin((dataf.a < 4).index)].index, inplace=True)
    return dataf
```

Then:

```py
for fn in ["addcol", "remcol", "addrow", "remrow"]:
    printer(tdf, fn)
# Output
addcol: DataFrame updated in place: shape1 = (5, 3), shape2 = (5, 3)
remcol: DataFrame updated in place: shape1 = (5, 2), shape2 = (5, 2)
addrow: DataFrame updated in place: shape1 = (6, 2), shape2 = (6, 2)
remrow: DataFrame updated in place: shape1 = (6, 2), shape2 = (6, 2)
```